# What killed my MQ channel?

Tags: ibm-midrange, ibm-mq

We have a process which runs regularly whenever we shut down our iSeries server. It performs the following (iSeries specific, but you can tell what the MQSC commands are) commands:

```
RCDMQMIMG  OBJ(*ALL) OBJTYPE(*ALL) DSPJRNDTA(*YES)
ENDMQMCSVR MQMNAME(IA001.QUEUE.MANAGER)
ENDMQM     MQMNAME(IA001.QUEUE.MANAGER)
DLYJOB     DLY(120)                    
ENDMQMLSR  MQMNAME(IA001.QUEUE.MANAGER)
```

Normally this runs without problems, however on the last occasion, five out of six channels ended normally and immediately and the sixth one ended abnormally approximately 75 seconds later.

From the log of the channel job, these two messages were consecutive (i.e. no intervening issues):

```
23/07/12  08:26:44.033529  LIBMQMCS_R   QMQM        *STMT    QCMD        QSYS        01C8
From module . . . . . . . . :   AMQXEIMX_R                                                  
From procedure  . . . . . . :   xcsSendMessage                                              
Statement . . . . . . . . . :   38                                                          
Message . . . . :   Channel 'IA001.TO.ISPRO' is starting.                                   
Cause . . . . . :   Channel 'IA001.TO.ISPRO' is starting.  Recovery  . . . :                
None.  Technical Description . . . . . . . . :   None.                                    

04/08/12  21:11:28.872098  QWTPITP2     QSYS        061A     *EXT                    *N  
Message . . . . :   Job ended abnormally.                                                   
Cause . . . . . :   A SIGKILL signal was received for the job. The action for               
the signal was to terminate the job.
```

Note that the ENDMQM does not use *WAIT to wait for the queue manager to end (the default *CNTRLD is in play), but I do not think that would have helped in this case, as I cannot find any evidence that any other process could have called a halt to proceedings. The forced end of the channel job occurred within the 120 second delay that has been manually inserted in the code (I know, we should use *WAIT, but this code is very old).

I think it is reasonable, perhaps, to assume the channel was processing messages when the queue manager was ended - otherwise why would 75 seconds elapse before the next action? It seems like the *CNTRLD option has an implied timeout, although I cannot see this discussed anywhere in documentation. Either that, or something else intervened. But what?

An ENDSBS *ALL did follow but I have proven that was several minutes after the channel died.

The interesting scenario this created for later was when the queue manager was restarted, there was an error issued saying the channel was already running, but the channel job appears exactly as it normally would, showing 'Channel starting' in the log and indeed it is running fine.

Any suggestions as to what external force may be involved or if there is a timeout would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of likely reasons for this.  The channel appears to be an outbound channel and it can be in a blocking network call when the QMgr is shut down. Alternatively, it can be in the middle of a batch and waiting on the other side to respond. If the other side is paused or the connection is broken, the channel may appear to hang while waiting on a response.

An inbound channel is often hard to stop if the listener is still running.  If the other side has messages to send and is enabled for triggering, it will immediately try to restart the channel.  This request hits the listener which starts the process. Since the QMgr is shutting down, the channel cannot complete its `CONNECT` but for a brief time there's a channel process running.

Whether inbound or outbound, the QMgr will eventually kill processes that don't come down on their own.  This should not be a problem since the channels will negotiate an orderly restart, although it does leave some errors in the log.

Tuning which factors into all of this includes TCP Keepalive, `HBINT`, `DISCINT`, channel retry parameters and the Adopt MCA parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

It is indeed an outbound channel. The odd thing is the system processes which use the queues that run over this channel were shut down several minutes beforehand, so it is highly unlikely anything was connected or that there were any messages still to be sent.

Clearly the queue manager 'cleaned up' at shutdown time but the actual problem that reared its head was on the restart.

Comment: Our startup process fires up the queue manager, command server and listener and then runs a script of MQ commands to start up all the outbound channels. This script execution failed on that channel saying it was 'in use' and when digging deeper that it was 'already running'.

I have assumed the link between the sudden death and the error on restart.

Comment: I'll look into the tuning parameters you suggested but I think this is a case of 'something was happening', as you suggested, but we'll never know exactly what that was.