# What is starting my MQ channels?

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-midrange

Following on from a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822442/what-killed-my-mq-channel) we have discovered some behaviour which I cannot understand with MQ channels.

At startup, we issue the following commands:

```
STRSBS SBSD(QMQM/QMQM)
STRMQM MQMNAME(IA001.QUEUE.MANAGER)
STRMQMCSVR MQMNAME(IA001.QUEUE.MANAGER)
STRMQMLSR MQMNAME(IA001.QUEUE.MANAGER)
DLYJOB DLY(300)
STRMQMMQSC SRCMBR(IA1_RESTRT) SRCFILE(MQSCRIPTS/MQSETUP) MQMNAME(IA001.QUEUE.MANAGER)
```

The script run at the end contains a series of channel start commands. Periodically we get an error in this step with a channel 'in use' and when investigating we find the channel is running.

The delay shown above was recently introduced as we thought the various pieces might need time to start properly before the channels were started, however this uncovered something curious in that we encountered the 'in use' error with three channels.

It seems that, given time, the channels are starting themselves. But I cannot figure out how or why? I'm not 100% familiar with channel initiation but from what I can learn from the documentation we do not have it set up – I scanned a configuration dump and found no entries of INITQ( ) with anything other than blanks.

What is starting our channels? I cannot replicate this behaviour on our test system at all.

Answer (score 1):

If a channel was previously in RETRYING status before the queue manager last ended, this state is remembered over the restart and your channel will be out back into RETRYING upon queue manager restart, and may then successfully connect.